# unit sphere in Q-dimensions and its relationship to volume and area of a sphere of any radius and dimension-Q

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, surface-integrals

I'm told that:

the surface Area of the unit sphere (r=1) in Q-dimensions is:

$$S_Q = \frac{2\pi^{Q/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{q}{2})}$$

and the volume of the unit sphere (r=1) in Q-dimensions is:

$$V_Q = \int_{0}^{1} S_Q~ r^{(Q-1)}~dr$$

$$V_Q = \frac{S_Q}{Q}$$

I'm trying to understand the formula for the general area, and general volume of Q-dimensional Sphere by multiply the unit volume ($V_Q$), and unit surface area ($S_Q$) by a function of radius. Specifically:

$$\tilde{S}_Q(r) = S_Q ~r^{Q-1}$$
$$\tilde{V}_Q(r) = V_Q ~r^Q$$

For instance, Why does multiplying the unit surface area $S_Q$ by $r^{Q-1}$ equal the Surface area for any sphere of radius r and dimension Q?

And, why does multiplying the unit volume by $r^Q$ equal the volume for any sphere of radius r and dimension Q?

Comment: if Q=3 for 3-dimensions, then the surface area of a 3-dimensional object can be unrolled into a 2-dimentional surface similar to the way a global is flatted onto a map.... now generalize for Q-dimensions and a Q-dimensional surface area, will unroll to a (Q-1) area... that's why $S_Q$ is multipled by (Q-1)....anyways, that's my theory of how it works...

Comment: Affine maps preserve the ratios of volumes and areas. So if we multiply by $r$ the radius of a 3d-sphere, its volume gets multiplied by $r^3$ and its surface area by $r^2$. In a generic dimension, it is just the same.